# Visual indication that lines have been truncated

Tags: wrapping

I recently went through and cleaned up my vimrc. In so doing, I inadvertently removed some code or a plugin that inserted a bluish `>` character at the end of lines that were truncated because they were wider than the buffer.

The only option I have now related wrapping is `set nowrap`. Which option is responsible for showing visual indication that a line has been truncated?

The `mg` editor shows a `$` at the right edge of a truncated line, as well as the left edge (`mg` always shows the leftmost part of "inactive" lines regardless of cursor position). Is there a way to mimic this behavior when scrolling horizontally?

Comment: "Cleaning up" is not exactly the same thing as "destroying".

Comment: @romainl The `listchars` thing ended up being hidden away in the `vim-sensible` plugin, which I got rid of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From vim help (`:h listchars`) :

> ```
> extends:c      Character to show in the last column, when 'wrap' is
>                off and the line continues beyond the right of the
>                screen.
> precedes:c     Character to show in the first column, when 'wrap'
>                is off and there is text preceding the character
>                visible in the first column.
> ```

So the following will set this characters:

```
set listchars=extends:>,precedes:<
```

Change them to your desired character and you could colorize them with following highlighting group:

```
hi NonText guifg=#ffffff ctermfg=gray
```